# TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createNode' of 'boundActionCreators' as it is undefined

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gatsby

Can anyone help with following error ?

```
ERROR #11321  PLUGIN

"gatsby-source-firestore" threw an error while running the sourceNodes lifecycle:

Cannot destructure property 'createNode' of 'boundActionCreators' as it is undefined.

24 |   const db = firebase.firestore();

25 |

26 |  const { createNode, createNodeField } = boundActionCreators;
          ^
 
27 |

28 |   const promises = types.map(

29 |     async ({ collection, type, populate, map = node => node }) => {

File: node_modules\gatsby-source-firestore\gatsby-node.js:26:11

TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'createNode' of 'boundActionCreators' as it is undefined.
```

Comment: I had the same error. Unfortunately I cannot explain why this works, but it worked for me: Try using `actions` instead of `boundActionCreators`.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing boundActionCreators by actions in gatsby-node.js present in node modules/gatsby-source-firestore
worked

Answer (score 0):

The fix for this issue is here: https://github.com/elboman/gatsby-remark-source-name/pull/1

Comment: this answer might benefit from more elaboration.